# Programatically creating divs with different background colors from a php array

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I have created divs in a MVC framework (Codeigniter).
From a data array, I am looping through the 'subject' array and making a div for each. I also added a header div and a content div for each subject. So, how do I make the background of the header in each subject have different colors from the colors array. They have to be different unless the number of the subjects is greater than the number of colors in the color array.

Here is the code for looping through each subject:

```
foreach ($userSubjects as $subject => $info) {
                echo "<div class='subject paper'>";
                    echo "<div class='subjectHeader'>";
                        echo $info['subject_name'];
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "<div class='subjectContent'>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
```

And here is the randColor array:

```
$colorSet = array(
    '#1abc9c',
    '#2ecc71',
    '#3498db',
    '#9b59b6',
    '#34495e',
    '#f1c40f',
    '#e67e22',
    '#e74c3c',
    '#ecf0f1',
    '#95a5a6'
);
```

Comment: Why you want to use PHP instead of CSS?

Comment: Because I want to dynamically apply these colors.

Comment: Then use CSS. This is not PHP trick

Comment: @DirkJan Aldry is trying to say that your results will be more maintainable if you use CSS for this instead of hard coding the values with PHP. You could either use the example below, or assign classes that contain the colours.

Comment: Okay, I get that now. I was over thinking things. Thanks!

Comment: @DirkJan : If your problem was clear, then mark my answer as answer.

Comment: @DirkJan PHP is not meant to do this you should consider jQuery

Comment: @meda - you're also wrong there, suggesting use of jQuery when no Javascript has even been mentioned is a bad idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best trick is using CSS instead of PHP :

```
div.subject:nth-child(10n+1) > .subjectHeader { background: #1abc9c}
div.subject:nth-child(10n+2) > .subjectHeader { background: #2ecc71}
div.subject:nth-child(10n+3) > .subjectHeader { background: #3498db}
div.subject:nth-child(10n+4) > .subjectHeader { background: #9b59b6}
div.subject:nth-child(10n+5) > .subjectHeader { background: #34495e}
div.subject:nth-child(10n+6) > .subjectHeader { background: #f1c40f}
div.subject:nth-child(10n+7) > .subjectHeader { background: #e67e22}
div.subject:nth-child(10n+8) > .subjectHeader { background: #e74c3c}
div.subject:nth-child(10n+9) > .subjectHeader { background: #ecf0f1}
div.subject:nth-child(10n+10) > .subjectHeader { background: #95a5a6}
```

To make it easier to use, you can use this script to generate CSS script;

```
<style type="text/css">
<?php
    $i = 1;
    foreach($colorSet as $c)
    {
         echo "div.subject:nth-child(".count($colorSet)."n+".$i.") > .subjectHeader { background: ".$c."}";
         $i++
    }
?>
</style>
```

Comment: Here's a PHP snippet to generate these definitions dynamically: `array_walk($colorSet, function($color, $i) {
 $css_i = $i + 1;
 echo 'div.subject:nth-child(' . $css_i . '*n) > .subjectHeader { background: \'' . $color . '\' } ';
});`

Comment: Why is the (1*n) needed? Isn't 1,2,3,...,10 enough?

Comment: If didnt use (*n), it only applies to 10 element only. So the 11th element wont get the background.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. When I tried using debugger, the element gets selected but the background color is not applied.

Comment: use !important, try "background #rrggbb !important;" in css rule.

Comment: When I remove the *n, the code works! There is something wrong with the *n.

Comment: @AldryWijaya the PHP code you've copied from my example won't work, you aren't incrementing `$i` - you can do it inline where you put it into the echo: `echo "div....." . $i++ . "etc...";`

Comment: I made it on my own. Fortunately, we had the same solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The best way (IMO) would be to use CSS classes to represent the colours. Start by defining your CSS styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
<?php
foreach($colorSet as $key => $color) {
    echo '.color' . $key . ' .subjectHeader { color: "' . $color . '"; }' . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
</style>
```

Then when you output your divs, output a color style with it:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($userSubjects as $subject => $info) :
    if(!isset($colorSet[$i]))
        $i = 0; // reset to the start of the array if you reach the end
    ?>
    <div class='subject paper color<?=$colorSet[$i++]?>'>
        <div class='subjectHeader'>
            <?=$info['subject_name']?>
        </div>
        <div class='subjectContent'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just have a counter variable and add the css as a style attribute.
saves you having to create a style tag for the css rules.

```
<?php
    $colourSet = array(
        '#1abc9c',
        '#2ecc71',
        '#3498db',
        '#9b59b6',
        '#34495e',
        '#f1c40f',
        '#e67e22',
        '#e74c3c',
        '#ecf0f1',
        '#95a5a6'
    );
    $numColours = count($colourSet);

    $colourInd = 0;

    foreach ($userSubjects as $subject => $info) {
?>
<div class="subject paper">
    <div class="subjectHeader" style="background: <?php echo $colourSet[$colourInd]; ?>">
        <?php echo $info['subject_name']; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="subjectContent">
    </div>
</div>
<?php
        $colourInd = ($colourInd + 1) % $numColours;
    }
?>
```

as this doesn't use nth-child it's backwards compatible with older browsers.
but considering it's only like older than IE8 that doesn't support that, it's not worth worrying about that really.

unless you're planning on dynamically loading these colours, then it's probably better to just define them as css rules like @Aldry-Wijaya suggested